# Strange Characters in Site Text

Tags: joomla-4.x, database, akeebabackup

- Joomla 4.2.5
- PHP 8.0.26

I've just noticed there are strange characters appearing throughout my website text - such as **â€™s**

Some of my pages are created with SP Page Builder, others with the default Joomla articles - they all contain the weird characters.

e.g. see the lines below;

**St Columb's School** now appears as **St Columbâ€™s School**

**each person's potential** now appears as **each personâ€™s potential**

**If you're not happy** now appears as **If youâ€™re not happy**

It seems to be affecting apostrophies. But weirdly, not them all - some pages are fine. There doesn't seem to be any consistency.

I've never noticed this until now. A lot of the content has been copied/pasted from various sources, but I always pasted as plain text.

Any ideas why this might happen, and how I can fix it without having to manually update the text?

I've checked my database and the characters are also there. I created the database using HeidiSQL, the collation is **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**

Comment: Related: [Getting â€™ instead of an apostrophe(') in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2292004/2943403) and ["â€™" showing on page instead of " ' "](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2477452/2943403) and [An apostrophe is rendering as â€tm. What PHP function will display it as ' ? something_Decode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4583369/2943403) and [â€™s comes up instead of apostrophe ' in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14665342/2943403) and [Convert â€™ to apostrophe in PHP and display to webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33079409/2943403)

Comment: And the granddaddy of them all: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems this was my mistake!

I was having issues with various aspects of the site so I decided to do some experimenting.

The steps I took to reproduce this are (using HeidiSQL);

1. took a dump of all the tables in my database
2. dropped the database
3. created a new database
4. imported the dump from step 1
5. special characters appeared

I think I was exporting or importing the dump as a different character encoding, possibly? I can't remember any of the export or import options I chose, but I'm guessing that was the cause.

I was able to restore the site using Akeeba without any issue, which I should have done from the beginning.

Take backups, use Akeeba, much easier.